# Duplicating Objects with Rigid Body Settings

Tags: physics, animation-nodes

I am using Animation Nodes' Object Instancer to duplicate an object with Rigid body settings. A far as I can tell, the physics settings are being duplicated on the cloned objects, but the physics engine is not recognizing the clones i.e. their outline is not green and the clones do not interact. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to enable the "Copy Full Object" checkbox?

Comment: Yes I have enabled that setting.Rigid body settings (animated, etc.) are being cloned, but the engine ignores it (and its outline is not green). I can toggle Rigid Body off and on, and the clone object works as expected.

Comment: ok, I just tested it. The problem is that the instances are not in the group named "RigidBodyWorld". You can use a loop and the Object Group Operations node to link all instances to the group. I created a todo on github to make this easier in the future: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/574

Comment: I added the Object Group Op. node and tied to RigidBody... group. When I examine the cloned object, it is a member of that group. Also, the cloned object's outline is green. Sadly, the physics engine ignores the clones until I manually toggle Rigid Body as before. BTW I am using AN to stack N cubes and running a sphere though the stack.

Comment: Did you disable Auto Execution when you start the simulation? Otherwise AN resets the location of the objects all the time.

Comment: OK. Go It!. I was adding to the group Rigid Body Constraints, not World. Also, I can leave Auto Execute enabled and the simulation works as expected. Thanks Again!

Comment: @JacquesLucke There's been a [follow-up question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73071/duplicating-objects-with-rigid-body-settings-in-animation-nodes-add-on) about the Object Group Operations loop that you mentioned. If you don't mind, I'll post an illustrated explanation of your comment as an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Kudos to *Jacques Lucke* for actually providing the solution in the comments above.

There are two conditions for an object to be considered in rigid body simulations:

#### A) Settings

The object has to include the actual *settings* for physics, accessible in the *Physics* tab of the *Property* area.

If you use *Animation Nodes*' **Object Instancer** to duplicate an object which already is set up for rigid body physics, then these settings will only be duplicated if **Copy Full Object** is selected.

[image: copy full object]

#### B) Group

Blender does only simulate objects which are in a special group called [*Rigid Body World*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/world.html). Enabling rigid body physics on an object in Blender's *native* interface does automatically create such a group, assign it to the scene (visible in the *Scene* tab of the *Properties* area) and add the object to that group.

Duplicating an object with *Animation Nodes* however does **not** copy that group information. Instanced objects have to be manually added, e.g. with the **Object Group Operation** node.

To add all instances of an object:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in the Node Editor and select **Subprograms** > **Loop** to add a **Loop Input** node
- Click on **New Iterator** and type `Object List` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again to add the **Object** > **Group Operations** node.
- In this node, click on the empty field of the first input node and choose the Rigid Body World group, named `RigidBodyWorld` by default.
  (If this group doesn't exist yet then you have to assign physics to some object first.)
- Connect the **Object** output of the *Loop Input* node with the matching input socket of the *Object Group Operations* node.
- (The **Linked** checkbox has to be enabled to add the objects to the group, but it should be by default.)

[image: loop and group operations]

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again, select **Subprograms** > **Invoke Subprogram** > **My Loop** (or however you might have called it) to actually use the loop.
- Connect the **Objects** output socket of your existing **Object Instancer** node with the **Object List** input socket of the **Invoke Subprogram** node.

[image: loop invocation]